# libgdx: Is is guaranteed that all of Screen methods are called from a single thread?

Tags: java, libgdx

The
[ApplicationListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/ApplicationListener.html) documentation seems to mean that all of `Game` methods are called from the GL Thread (of which there's only one).

`Game` defers to the current `Screen`.

[Screen documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) doesn't talk about threading.

Is there any guarantee that none of the `Screen` methods can be called concurrently? 
(i.e. `hide` will be called after `render` completes, not in the middle of it)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

[libGDX Threading Wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading) provides more documentation on the subject.

Since `Game` (`ApplicationListener`) defers to `Screen`, one could expect that all `Screen` methods are called from the main GL thread and can not be called concurrently unless **the developper** messes with `Screen` outside the GL thread, in other words, without using `Application.postRunnable`.